# localstorage available after upgrade

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension with a fair number users and it uses localstorage to store their information. When I put a new version out, will the localstorage remain?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Local storage will remain in clients' local machines. However, you should keep in mind that users can clear their local storage data easily. Local storage is also limited to 5MB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the whole point of localStorage.